# Android how to parse link in jsoup so that if web link is changed its automatically changed in app

Tags: android, hyperlink, jsoup

I am using jsoup for parsing html but i want to parse link so that if in future the website url or a part of url is changed its automatically changed in app also,
suppose i have a link below:

http://www.nhl.com/ice/playerstats.htm?season=20132014&gameType=2&team=ANA&position=S&country=&status=&viewName=summary

this link is for specific season that is **season=20132014** which is mention in the link its change from year to year this link is for season 2013-2014, how i parse this link in jsoup so that if this season code is changed my app also changed it,
this is what i am doing here in code:

```
 String BLOG_URL="http://www.nhl.com/ice/playerstats.htm?season=20132014&gameType=2&team=ANA&position=S&country=&status=&viewName=summary";
 Document document = Jsoup.connect(BLOG_URL).get();
    Element nodeBlogStats = document.getElementById("forwards");
    for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element row : nodeBlogStats.select("tr")) {
        for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element column : row.select("td")) {
            for (int i = 0; i <= 5; i++) {
                for (org.jsoup.nodes.Element n : column.select("td#LW" + i)) {
                    result += column.text();
                }
            }
        }
        result = "<u>" + result + "</u>";
        result += "<br><br>";
    }
```

I want to dynamically/automatically update this BLOG_URL if orignal is changed,
Thanks in advance

Comment: Any one know how to do this please help

Comment: where do you get the original link from? why don't you just create a link for the old season "20122013" or what do you want?

Comment: i want to setup a season 20132014 at a time and in future how i update  this when its changes to 20142015

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can create the "next" season link and use jsoup to get the results. You see that in the moment the link

```
String BLOG_URL="http://www.nhl.com/ice/playerstats.htm?season=20142015&gameType=2&team=ANA&position=S&country=&status=&viewName=summary";
```

will lead to a site stating that the pageis not available. You can scrape for this info and ignore the link. However if it becomes available, your application can switch to the new link and test then for the next one "20152016" until this becomes available.